# Overlaping of html and css based boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to overlap two "sign in" and "sign out" boxes over "or" box. I trying the below coding?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4TA2/)

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <div class="signin">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#loginmodal" id="modaltrigger">
          <h6>Signin</h6>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="a">
        <h6>or</h6>
      </li>
      <li class="b">
        <a href="signup.html">
          <h6>Signup</h6>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.signin {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -26px;
}

.signin ul li {
}

.signin li a h6 {
    padding: 0px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background: #1371B3;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-right: -35px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.signin li a:hover {
    color: #76AE41;
}

.signin li.a   h6 {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    float: left;
    background: #1065A1;
    border-radius: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: -35px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.signin li.b a h6 {
    padding: 0px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #1371B3;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-radius: 0 2em 2em 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.signin li b :hover {
    color: #76AE41;
}
```

there are some css problem for defining the class.Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you have full control of the HTML and CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y4TA2/2/ what changes do you want to it best draw it in paint where you want to position it and save as png and attach it to your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you out:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4TA2/3/)**

Add the below CSS and remove all of the `margin:` entries on your `h6` tags.

CSS:

```
/* new css */
.signin ul li {
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
}
.b {left: 150px;}
.a {
    left: 120px; 
    top: 10px; 
    z-index: 100;
}

/* old css */
.signin {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -26px;
}

.signin   li ,ul {
   list-style:none; 
}

.signin li a h6 {
    padding: 0px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    //float: left;
    background: #1371B3;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    //vertical-align: middle;
    //margin-top: -15px;
    //margin-right: -35px;
    //z-index: 1;
    //position: relative;
}

.signin li a:hover {
    color: #76AE41;
}

.signin li.a   h6 {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    //float: left;
    background: #1065A1;
    border-radius: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    //vertical-align: top;
    //margin-top: 12px;
    //margin-right: -35px;
    //z-index: 1;
    //position: relative;
}

.signin li.b a h6 {
    padding: 0px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    //float: left;
    //vertical-align: middle;
    background: #1371B3;
    //margin-top: -5px;
    border-radius: 0 2em 2em 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    //position: relative;
}

.signin li b :hover {
    color: #76AE41;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have full control of HTML and CSS, and I have predicted the result you are going for, here's how I would go about it.

http://jsfiddle.net/9b6YS/

HTML

```
<div class="signin">
    <a href="#loginmodal" id="modaltrigger">Signin</a>
    or 
    <a href="signup.html">Signup</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.signin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1371B3;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.signin a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.signin a:hover {
    color: #76AE41;
}
```

Note that I dropped the complexity. It doesn't seem to add anything, but perhaps you know something I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you wolud like them overlapped and on a single line then I would recommend not using `float` in this instance and instead use `display: inline-block`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/y4TA2/4/

```
.signin li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for the class "a" is targeting the H6 or box because you said you want to target the LI with the class of "a".

Your first "sign" LI in button has no class. Try changing it to:

```
<li class="a">
    <a href="#loginmodal" id="modaltrigger">
        <h6>Signin</h6>
 </li>
 <li >
     <h6>or</h6>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click For Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4TA2/5/)

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li> <div class="signin"> <span >sign in</span> </div></li>

    <li><div class="Or"> <span > or </span> </div></li>
    <li><div class="signOut"> <span >sign Out</span> </div></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
.signin{

    background-color:#1371B3;
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
        border-top-left-radius:10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
     text-align:center;    
     z-index:2;    
      margin-right:-3px;   
    border:1px solid #0c456e;
}
.signin span{

    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
}
.Or{
        background-color:#1371B3;
    height:35px;
    width:50px;
        border-radius:10px;
    margin-top:-5px;

 text-align:center;   
     z-index:1;    
       border:1px solid #0c456e;a
}
.Or span{

    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;

}
.signOut{

    background-color:#1371B3;
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
      border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 z-index:2px;    
      margin-left:-3px;    
        border:1px solid #0c456e;
}

.signOut span{

    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
     text-align:center;  

}
ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;

}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

after reading all the answers here, I think you are going for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/s6KF8/2/

```
<div class="signin">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#loginmodal" id="modaltrigger" class="login">
      <h6>Signin</h6>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="or_circle">
    <h6>or</h6>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a href="signup.html" class="signup">
      <h6>Signup</h6>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and for css

```
.signin{
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
}
.signin h6 {
    margin:0;
}
.signin li {
   list-style:none; 
   float:left;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   color: #ffffff;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.signin a {
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
}

.login {
    border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: #1371B3;
    margin-right:-10px;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.signup { 
    border-radius: 0 2em 2em 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: #1371B3;
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-top:8px;
}

.or_circle{
    border-radius: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #1371B3;
    position:relative;
}

a.signup:hover,a.login:hover {
    background: #76AE41;
}
```